# Is this possible method of delivery ad-hoc version to customer?

Tags: ios

I heard that there is a mechanism to deliver ad-hoc version app for client uses url.

1. We create .ipa file with all settings (provisioning profile, sdk
   version etc.)
2. We upload our .ipa file on sever and give our customer url of this
   app
3. Customer go to this link on device and the application will be
   download and install on device

Is there any such way? If not - I think this question must be closed (and I closed it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Testflight](http://www.testflightapp.com/) does a good job - if you want to have more control and run this on your own server, take a look at [Hockey](http://hockeykit.net/).